# How to convert response message returned from HttpResponseMessage from POST Method to C# class in a TestMethod?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

There is a piece of code in Post() method in Web Api. This post method returns HttpResponseMessage using Request.CreateResponse to TestMethod. 
In the TestMethod(), I need to convert the response returned from Post() method to C# class. I tried couple of approaches, but no luck.

Can anyone of you please suggest me how we can achieve above functionality?

Comment: Use the `content` property of the `httpresponsemessage`. If you are not using `httpclient` (`webclient` maybe) then this would be serialized which you can parse as `json` or `xml` depending on your content negotiation. This can then be mapped to your POCO.

Answer (score 0):

First you need an object

```
  public class MyObject {
  public string Id {get;set;}
  public string Text {get;set;}
  ...
   }
```

Then try  this

```
using (var twitpicResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) {

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(twitpicResponse.GetResponseStream())) {
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var objText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        MyObject myojb = (MyObject)js.Deserialize(objText,typeof(MyObject));
    }

}
```